# How to store data over time in Django ORM?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I would like to store numerical data that corresponds to a certain date, as in stock prices. Each stock would have a list of days and a corresponding price for that day.

I am aware of Django's ArrayField, but that wouldn't work as a dictionary; I'd have to have two separate arrays with the indices of each day and price matching up.

In theory a One:Many relationship between the stock and the day, with a One:One relationship beteen day and the price could work, but this seems very inefficient. Am I correct in thinking so?

This is what some data might look like in pure Python

```py
appl = {Datetime.date(2000, 1, 1): 100,
        Datetime.date(2000, 1, 2): 200}
googl = {Datetime.date(2010, 1, 1): 100,
         Datetime.date(2010, 1, 2): 200} #etc
```

I'm using Python 3.6, Django 2.2 and PostgreSQL for the database. What is a way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store it in three columns: date, stock and price.

```py
class Store(Model):
    stock = CharField(max_length=10)
    date = DateTimeField()
    price = FloatField()
```